# Gnuplot : xtics - place strings at tics

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot, and am trying to create a stacked histogram for a project. The problem I am running into is, that I am not able to put ticlabels on the x-axis (even if I could, they are not getting formatted in a neat way). My gp file is as follows:

Here is a snapshot of my data file:

```
CC P1-X P1-Y P2-X P2-Y
1 0.1097586  0.3262812  1.980848  5.9098402
2 0.1010986  0.2988812  0.9966702  5.8378412
3 0.4017474  0.7559452  4.41813  11.7404132
4 0.1028442  0.2974772  1.418744  6.0554552
5 0.1097316  0.3216112  1.967492  5.8007364
6 0.954794  0.3004874  0.9568386  5.778537
```

And here is my gp file:

```
set title "GCC compilation option by average execution time as stacked histogram"
set terminal jpeg medium
set output "histosmalldata.jpeg"
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set key autotitle columnheader
set key outside right top vertical Left reverse enhanced autotitles columnhead nobox
set key invert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 
set style histogram rowstacked title  offset character 0, 0, 0
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0
set xtics norangelimit
set xtics ("O2-ffast-math-finline-functions" 1, "O2-funroll-loops-march=barcelona-ffast-math-finline-functions" 2, "GCCFLAGS_O0" 3, "O2-ftree-vectorize-funroll-loops-march=barcelona" 4, "GCCFLAGS_O2" 5, "O2-ftree-vectorize-funroll-loops-ffast-math" 6)
set xtics 1,6 nomirror 
set ytics 0,100 nomirror
set ytics 1
set yrange [0:20]
set ylabel "Time"
set xlabel "GCC Compiler Options"
plot 'smalldata' using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' using 3 ti col, '' using 4 ti col, '' using 5 ti col
```

This is the image of the graph:
[image]

Now, in the x axis, I am having 1,2,3 - 6 which I don't want, instead, I would want "O2-ffast-math-finline-functions" for 1 and so on in a neat formatted way.

I wrote this script after consulting some examples from gnuplot page and do not have a good understanding of some of the verbs, so apart from the solution, any general comments are welcome.

Thank you,
Sayan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not overwrite your `xtics` settings after you specified what you want.

Put all options into a single `set` command:

```
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0\
         norangelimit\
         ("O2-ffast-math-finline-functions" 1,\
          "O2-funroll-loops-march=barcelona-ffast-math-finline-functions" 2,\
          "GCCFLAGS_O0" 3, "O2-ftree-vectorize-funroll-loops-march=barcelona" 4,\
          "GCCFLAGS_O2" 5, "O2-ftree-vectorize-funroll-loops-ffast-math" 6)
```

Note that you can escape the newline with a backslash as the last character of the line.

Comment: Thank you, but even after combining all xtics statements, the graph remains almost the same with an exception when I try to run the script: line 22: warning: difficulty making room for xtic labels .... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, that I do not actually need to specify ticlabels because that information is in my source file.
So I modified my source file like:

```
set title "GCC compilation option by average execution time as stacked histogram"
set terminal png size 1500,1200 font "/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf, 13"
set output 'hist_gcc_1.png'
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set key outside right top vertical Left reverse enhanced autotitles columnhead nobox
set key invert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 
set style histogram rowstacked title offset character 0, 0, 0
set datafile missing '-' 
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45 offset character 0, 0, 0     norangelimit
set ytics 0,100 nomirror
set ytics 1
set yrange [0:20]
set ylabel "Time"
set xlabel "GCC Compiler Options"
plot 'data' using 2:xticlabels(1) ti col, '' using 3 ti col, '' using 4 ti col, '' using 5 ti col
```

My dat file looks like:

```
CC P1-X P1-Y P2-X P2-Y
O2-ffast-math-finline-functions 0.1097586  0.3262812  1.980848 5.9098402
O2-funroll-loops-march=barcelona-ffast-math-finline-functions 0.1010986 0.2988812  0.9966702 5.8378412
GCCFLAGS_O0 0.4017474 0.7559452 4.41813 11.7404132
...
```